# sqlite3.c breaks when stdint.h is included?

Tags: c, sqlite

This is a bit of a strange question, but if you download the latest version (3340000) of the sqlite3.c amalgamation from the website and add `#include <stdint.h>` to the top with no other changes, and compile with `gcc -o sqlite3.o -c sqlite3.c`, you get the following errors:

```
sqlite3.c:34147:42: error: ‘mremap’ undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean ‘munmap’?
   { "mremap",       (sqlite3_syscall_ptr)mremap,          0 },
                                          ^~~~~~
                                          munmap
sqlite3.c: In function ‘unixRemapfile’:
sqlite3.c:38766:42: error: ‘MREMAP_MAYMOVE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     pNew = osMremap(pOrig, nReuse, nNew, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sqlite3.c:38766:42: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
sqlite3.c:38766:42: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘(void * (*)(void *, size_t,  size_t,  int,  ...))aSyscall[24].pCurrent’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
sqlite3.c:38766:42: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct unix_syscall *’
```

Also, clang gives different errors. It seems odd to me that sqlite3 breaks in the presence of stdint.h, especially when that file can usually be included many times over in a project without conflict.

I know some of you may want to ask why I'm attempting this, but please avoid that question, I just want to focus on the question itself here. So does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Why do you need to modify the source file to begin with? Isn't it supposed to be working as it is already?

Comment: Possible answer, it was going to include some header after defining some thing or another (possibly changing the behavior of the included headers). This header was probably included by `stdint.h` first without that definition, breaking code expectations.

Comment: Probably it defines [feature test macros](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) before including any headers.

Comment: You were right Shawn, thank you! `#define _GNU_SOURCE` needed to be added before `stdint.h`